# RTX implementation with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rtos, rtx

I have to implement the [RTOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) [RTX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTX_(operating_system)) on a [Nucleo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32#Nucleo_boards)-F411RE board ([Cortex-M4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Cortex-M4)). I have to do it with Eclipse, but I don't know how I should do it.

Moreover, I tried to compile it with the GCC compiler, and I had many errors like :

```
_ error: stray '#' in program
_ error: expected '(' before 'void' __asm void rt_set_PSP (U32 stack) {
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The name RTX refers to more that one product.  Given your target I assume Keil RTX?

Comment: Yes it is Keil RTX.

Answer (score 0):

Keil's MDK-ARM includes a [plug-in for Eclipse](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ecluv/default.htm) as an alternative to using µVision.  That would be the most straightforward way to start developing with Eclipse.  It supports importing/exporting projects to and from µVision.

The errors you have are most likely due to attempting to compile ARM RealView compiler (armcc) specific code with gcc.